# app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac after removing package

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, build, build.gradle

I'm new to react native, my gradle version is 2.1.3 and after I have installed react-native-linear-gradient package, the app won't build, so I've removed it (first unlink and remove command).
Now when I build the app I'm facing this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the compiler has a problem in the MainApplication.java file on line 26. 
The problem is the ");". You should look inside the file an try to fix it. After that you can navigate to the android folder using your terminal and execute following command: "gradlew clean" or if you are using powershell its something like "./gradlew clean".

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not enough Data. Please send a screenshot of MainApplication.java. I think there could be a problem of Opening and closing Brackets.

If you are removing a package make sure there is no traces of it in settings.gradle, build.gradle and MainApplication.java after unlinking and deleting package.